# Failure writing sector ... to HD0 when external drive disconnected - Kubuntu

Tags: boot, hard-drive, kubuntu

I have external WD Element 750GB drive for keeping files and a laptop with SSD 250GB with Kubuntu.

When I have the external WD connected, the boot is OK, but when I disconnect it and power on the laptop, tells me "Failure writing sector 0x33b5000 to 'HDD0'

Have the system (Kubuntu 16.10) or the laptop "adopted" the external HDD or whatever?

Comment: Check the boot device priorities in you bios.

Comment: Boot priorities look well - EFI part., HDD0, HDD1, ... USB key, USB HDD, Network..